# Call method with Mono.Cecil

Tags: c#, mono

I have a question about Mono.Cecil.
I have method `m` in class `C` in namespace `NS`. The method returns `String`.
I need to inject IL code into another method in other class that will call `m` method.
How to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `MethodDefinition.Body.GetILProcessor()` to receive an `ILProcessor` object. That allows you to further modify the method body and inject whatever IL code you want to add.

You might get some basic ideas from `Obfuscar.HideStrings` where new classes and methods are created from scratch,

https://github.com/lextm/obfuscar/blob/master/Obfuscar/Obfuscator.cs

There are other open source projects based on Cecil, too.